# JQuery slideToggle slides down in the wrong part of the page and then jumps back

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple log in and sign up form, you have the option to log in and if you don't have a log in you click the sign up button. I then want the sign up form to drop down but when I do it drops down the side of the page and then pops into the middle where it should be. Annoyingly it works fine on fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/frankbsph/kf95Lrxv/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Drive Control</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fluid-container">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                <h1>Welcome To Drive Control</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fluid-container signIn">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <form id="log" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-horizontal">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="form-horizontal">Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>  
                        <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
                <div id="error">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
        <div class="fluid-container signUp">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <form action= method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-horizontal">First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-horizontal">Last Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-horizontal">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="form-horizontal">Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>  
                        <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine to me.

Comment: @nfn-neil it does in fiddle but I think that's because it is a small window so the bootstrap formatting seems to help it out but the problem occurs on a full web browser, sorry I wasn't clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:** class name "container-fluid" not fluid-container.

**Problem 2:** place the signUp button without the col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 under class name .signIn 
[liveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xretexpx/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".signUp").hide();

$(".signUpBtn").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
     $(".signIn").slideToggle("slow",function(){
      $(".signUp").slideToggle("slow");
     });
    });
})
```

```html
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <title>Drive Control</title>
 
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
   <h1>Welcome To Drive Control</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid signIn">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <form id="log" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-horizontal">Email</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label class="form-horizontal">Password</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </div> 
     <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
   </form>
   <div id="error">
    <p></p>
   </div>
  
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block signUpBtn">Sign Up</button> </div>
 </div>
 
 
 
 <div class="container-fluid signUp">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-horizontal">First Name</label> 
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-horizontal">Last Name</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-horizontal">Email</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label class="form-horizontal">Password</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </div> 
     <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this all works great. Embarrassing that I got that container wrong :s